# Android Application showing different results on running back to back

Tags: android

I am working on an android app which shows some value after running through an algorithm but surprisingly it is showing different values each time i run the application for same input values. 
I think it is some type of android system problem.
Can anyone help me out on this.

Comment: Without any more information, no. There's no code snippet at least you can add?

Comment: Your question is too generic. Can you give more details ?

Answer (score 4):

Without any actual code it's very close to impossible for someone to give you an accurate answer. With that said, the only thing that could even be suggested really is that **you're either depending on a system/state dependent variable to do your calculations, or possibly even not initializing your variables properly, thus leaving them in a non-zero state to begin with??**. Post some more code, and until then maybe try something like:

- Place breakpoints within your code so you can analyze values of variables, and walk through your code more comprehensively.
- Use the `Log.d()` functionality to give you some values to work from in `LogCat`.
- When you've done those and can't find your answer, go here [DDMS - Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

Comment: when i am running the application on emulator it's showing the expected result but on  running the app on device it shows a different result. I am quite sure there  is no system/state dependent variable that i am using and in what manner not initializing the variables may be effecting the result.